# Stock Prices Not Scraping With Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Used this tutorial to scrape stock prices: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2h41uEi0xU

There are some similar questions, but I want to know how to fix this current code (for learning purposes) where these just have work arounds.

[Web scraping information other than price from Yahoo Finance in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581106/web-scraping-information-other-than-price-from-yahoo-finance-in-python-3)

[Using Regex to get multiple data on single line by scraping stocks from yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587592/using-regex-to-get-multiple-data-on-single-line-by-scraping-stocks-from-yahoo)

I understand there are better ways to do this, however these videos are helpful to learn.

Everything is working, but it isn't retrieving the prices from the site! I have the exact code he has too. I am using Python Launcher (Mac) 2.7 (tried 3.4 as well) to run the python program.

Here's my code:

```
import urllib
import re

symbolslist = ["aapl", "spy", "goog", "nflx"]
i=0
while i<len(symbolslist):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" +symbolslist[i] +"&q1=1"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id ="yfs_l84_'+symbolslist[i] +'">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "the price of" , symbolslist[i], " is " ,price
    i+=1
```

Comment: If you are going to learn you may as well learn the correct way, parsing html with regex is not a good idea

Comment: You can also iterate over the elements of symbolslist directly, using range is redundant. `for i in symbolslist`, then just use i instead of `symbolslist[i]`

Answer (score 2):

1. There is an extra space after id in your regex. The correct regex would be: 
   (see the sample code below).
2. price is a list, so to get the price, you need to use price[0].

Sample code:

```
>>> regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_"yfs_l84_'+symbolslist[i] +'"">(.+?)</span>'
>>> pattern = re.compile(regex)
>>> price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
>>> price
[u'568.77']
>>> price[0]
u'568.77'
```

Comment: the space is the problem not using `symbolslist[i]`

Comment: Yes, space is the problem and also price[0] should be used. I used goog instead of symbolslist[i] to check quickly if it works.

Comment: well probably better to use the code as the OP has to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

[It is never a good idea to parse HTML using regular expression.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) I suggest using a parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de) to parse for you. Also, another change I would make is not using a while loop. Use a for loop instead like I do. I see you have defined i and are incrementing it anyway, so a for loop makes more sense in this context.

But as for what is wrong with your regex expression, Tamim is right, you have an extra space in the `id=` part of your expression.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

symbolslist = ["aapl", "spy", "goog", "nflx"]
for i in range(0, len(symbolslist)):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" +symbolslist[i] +"&q1=1"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    idTag = 'yfs_l84_' + symbolslist[i]
    price = bs.find('span', {'id': idTag}).text
    print "the price of" , symbolslist[i], " is " ,price
```